# Dont work setVisible

Tags: android, firebase

**The menu should be hidden if the condition**
**I don't know why this code doesn't work.**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            String admin = "shcherbuk96@mail.ru";
            if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail() == admin) {
                MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.settings_item_1);
                menuItem.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.settings_item_1:
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_User.class));
                        break;

                    case R.id.settings_item_2:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Вышел", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below code :**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String admin = "shcherbuk96@mail.ru";
        String email=null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.settings_item_1:
                    email=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                    if (email!=null && email.equalsIgnoreCase(admin)) {
                        item.setVisible(false);
                    }else {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_User.class));
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.settings_item_2:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Вышел", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: it works but menu has this item. 
If I click on this method, it disappears

Comment: @shcherbuk, That is what you are trying to implement ?

Comment: Yes, only it is necessary for the item to immediately run if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: @shcherbuk, Happy coding!

Comment: @shcherbuk, I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 2):

email is string, you need to check with `string1.equals("string2")`, `string1 == string2` gives you false (2 different objects)

change `if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail() == admin)`

with `if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().equals(admin))`

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your firebase configuration. Did you try debugging? What does your FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail() give?

Comment: Also even if your firebase auth doesnt work, DO change the string comparison to what i said. String object is kinky, you cant check the way you're doing.

Comment: Oooo,if i am using this item in emulator, he give me error.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)

Comment: do you have your permissions?

Comment: For what?
_____

Answer (score 0):

Beside the Obvious change of `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail() == admin` to `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().equalIgnoreCase(admin)`, If you plan to hide the menu item on click you must edit the menu item itself.
the `findViewById(R.id.settings_item_1)` give you a View Object not MenuItem.
For Example this will hide the menuItem you just clicked:

```
item.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to get desired result

`getMenu().findItem(R.id.settings_item_1).setVisible(false);`

or

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.settings_item_1);
item.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    String admin = "shcherbuk96@mail.ru";
    String email=null;
    email=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    if (email!=null && email.equalsIgnoreCase(admin)) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.settings_item_1).setVisible(false);

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings_item_1:{
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_User.class));
                break;
            }
        case R.id.settings_item_2:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Вышел", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```